# Apply permutation to generate a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, permutation

I have the following Key Value pairs for which i need to find all combinations based on the key. In the figure the first table shows the all the key value pairs and the second table shows the extract of the expected output. All possible combinations should make the table.

[image: This is the extract of the table i am trying to build]

```
public ActionResult ViewSystemValues ()
{
    var model = new List<ViewSystemValuesVM>();//Each item in Model consists of the Key Value pair mentioned in the question         
    var tclist = new List<TcSet>(); //Each item is the link to the Property that holds the key
    var tcid = new List<int>(); //List of distinct keys in tclist              

    //For simplicity I have eliminated the code that would populate the Lists  and the model with the description as comments

    string[] myArray = new string[tclist.Count()];
    var model1 = new List<String[]>();
    int tclistcount = tclist.Count();
    foreach(var x in model)
    {
        foreach (var item in model)
        for(int i=0;i<tclistcount;i++)
        {         
            if (tcid[i] == item.TcSetID)
                myArray[i] = item.Value; 
        }
        model1.Add(myArray);
    }
}
```

**Approach**

`myArray` corresponds to one row in  my permuted table. `model` holds the valid Key Value pairs. I check if the key from the `model` and `tcid` are same the value can be added in the `myArray` with the index same as `tcid` so that I get the corresponding values for the `tcid`.

But I only get the last possible  combination

```
colour  fruit    vegatable
yellow  banana    beans 
yellow  banana    beans 
yellow  banana    beans 
yellow  banana    beans 
yellow  banana    beans 
yellow  banana    beans
```

Comment: Your description is not too clear (and you shouldn't refer to an external post; it doesn't matter if the site belongs to SE), but your code has various bits which are most likely wrong (or not ideal). For example: the two most external foreach loops ( foreach(var x in model) & foreach (var item in model)) are doing something which you certainly don't want: iterating through all the elements in model times all the elements in model; in fact you are not even using the variable iterating through the first loop (x). Other not-too-right issue (and/or weird) is var model1 = new List<String[]>();.

Comment: Additionally, the original post (whose contents should be included here) is not describing what you want clearly. Building an algorithm for you is not precisely on-topic here (and I think that neither in Programmers); but you might get some hints if you describe the situation properly. For example: provide a sample input set (a simplistic one) and describe the exact behaviour you want to accomplish.

Comment: But  haven't i included a sample output and the output that i am getting now? And in the previous question there is an image of the input. But I can add the the input set to this question

Comment: All the contents of my comments are advices, whose goal is trying to help you (to use SO properly, to get help quickly, to create a right algorithm, etc.). You are free to ignore them. But please let's not waste the time on a discussion with no clear point (not to me, at least).

Comment: OK. Sorry, you are right. You have done everything perfect, continue like this.

Comment: I was just asking? There is no need of sarcasm here. I will edit my question beacuse I am seeking help. and I want the person who is willing to help understand what I am really trying to achieve. I will surely add a better description. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: This is much better. But rather than writing your wrong outputs; it would be much clearer to write the outputs you expect. I understand that you want: red apple onion -- red apple potato -- red apple tomato, etc.

Comment: In any case, my advice for this kind of situations where you have to create all the possible combinations among a limited (and much more important: perfectly-defined and always constant) number of variables is keeping it really simple by relying on as many nested loops as variables (and bearing in mind that the combinations are generated in the most inner loop). This would work fine and would be easy to write and debug. The picture might become much more complicated with a variable number of variables (i.e., now 2 and tomorrow 20). Is this enough or you need more help?

Comment: I thought i could calculate the number of total permutations and fill the table beacuse i realised this when i made the sample table above where i did the copy paste for the table content. But the number of `keys` is not constant for me to write loops. The output expected is in the picture and the output that i get with my code is the below one.

Comment: If the number of keys (involved variables) is not constant, the complexity increases. When dealing with these situations is very easy to get lost and to create not too good algorithms; my suggestion above avoids this kind of problems by keeping it simple and easily controllable. If you cannot rely on it you would have to think carefully about the algorithm to build (sorry but SO is not the place for this). Bear in mind that knowing the number of combinations is easy but not helpful: the whole deal is creating the given combinations (i.e., writing each string in the right order).

Comment: Where on SE is the best place for me to ask for an algorithm(Does it really have a place where I could ask one when i have no idea what could be done)? i have thought a lot to find an approach to do this. But I couldn't find any except the one above which isnt right. But if atleast i could find the right inner loop to find the right combination i could try it.

Comment: I recommend you to build something a bit more simple but working fine to help you understand the problem properly and then keep evolving it (in fact, this is exactly what I would do in this situation myself). Go ahead and build the nested loops I suggested; that is: assume that the problem has a limited number of variables and create a solution for it. Do you understand what I mean or shall I write a small code showing how to do that?

Comment: if you don't feel offended please give me some time to try on my own. i will get back if i am not successful with a fixed number of key and values. I will add the code that i get to the question.

Comment: Why would I get offended? I do prefer people quickly/properly understanding what I say rather than having to further explain anything. You can take my help as you wish (as mere inspiration if you prefer). In any case and as said I will not deliver a ready-to-use solution for your problem (unless it is simple enough). PS: I don't think that there is any SE site delivering what you want; some people might not mind to write some code for simple requests (even despite of being slightly off-topic), but your conditions (the variable number of inputs bit) are not simple.

Comment: Do you think there would be a way for me to achieve this? or an added detail of my data model could help? because the explanation in my question contains more of my approach of generating the key value pair list and then trying to permute. Maybe based on my model there could be another approach to do it as the value in the kv pair could be accessed from the parent class. i thought permuting a list would be something that i culd find a solution for.

Comment: As said, you are free to take my help or not; but please try to understand it (= just with this I am more than happy). My ideas on this front are: you should explain clearly what you want (what you have done with your last editions; although it might be even better if you would include the desired output, rather than the erroneous one delivered by your current algorithm). SO (and I think that any other SE site) is not meant for custom-building anything; although some people might write a code for you if the conditions are clear and simple enough...

Comment: ... Your problem is simple enough if the number of variables is constant. At least, it might be solved by relying on a systematic and no-errors-prone approach (as suggested above: as many nested loops as variables; I might write down a simple code to show what I mean if this idea is not clear). But with a variable number of input variables, its complexity increases notably and that's why I don't think that anyone will build a code for you. These are all my ideas on this front; I might be wrong and/or you might not like to take them. But please let's stop discussing about what is clear :)

Comment: I have added the required output. Its in the figure. May be i haven't explained it in the question. The lower table in the figure shows the required output. I will mention it in the question as well. I was thinking making this table would be easy till now, but now I don't feel so. This is the last part in my project. I am trying the code for fixed number of variables. Will get back in an hour or so. Edited the question with the detail of the image. The detail was within the description which was not displayed.

Comment: OK (didn't realise about the pic), up to you.

Comment: This is exactly what I was talking about: something simple and working for sure. Not efficient?! Why not? The only limitation of this approach is that can only deal with 3 variables (or with as many variables as loops you are putting in); it is not scalable/adaptable to changing input conditions; other than that, it is perfect. Bear in mind that a trying-everything approach is usually something to be avoided at all cost; but if this is exactly what you want, you cannot get it in a more efficient way (perhaps a LINQ based approach might slightly better, but would be much more confusing).

Comment: What you might definitively want to consider is to rely on more efficient types/intermediate storage; a 3D Tuple is certainly very inefficient. Also if you want to just display these values as string, why not storing everything in 1-D collection (with the exact format to display them)?

Comment: You mean writing HTML code? `<table><tr><td>row1 col1</td><td>row1 col2</td><td>row1 col3</td></tr><table>`? You can store the values in this format right away in a 1-D string collection (array/list) rather than relying on the tremendously-high-memory-consuming 3D tuples. Or even don't store the information anywhere and create the table in the same spot where the new permutations are generated. But this is already way too off-topic; you should better continue by your own or ask a different question.

Comment: I did not ask about writing the HTML. I still could not manage to generate the rows for the table. As in the sample(colours,fruit,veg) i could do the same for real data. Create a list of key and its possible values. Now I am struggling to permute the values. Did I explain it the right way? Should I edit my question with what I have got so far? making it simpler for someone trying to help? But I really dont wanna mess it up. :)

Comment: As said, this has gone already too far (this is not how SO is expected to be used; it is not about solving your specific problems via comments, but about asking generic enough questions which might helpful to others). So this will be my last help (please, don't take it bad). If I want to create a table for a website (= HTML) from the information you have, I would create the 3 loops you did and, inside the inner loop, I would replace combi.Add... with: string line = "<tr><td>" + col + "</td><td>" + fru + "</td><td>" + veg + "</td><td><tr>"; I would store line in List<string> allLines; or...

Comment: ... even better I would not store anything and just write "<table>" before starting the loops and "</table>" after all the loops has ended. And replace the aforementioned line variable with plainly printing these values out. The result? After existing the loops the table with all the contents would have been generated without having stored (and write and read) anything. If you have problems to understand this new suggestion or it doesn't answer your exact concerns I would be really sorry, but as said, I have wasted too much time here already (happy to be helpful, but don't expect this again).

Comment: Thanks that you brought it so far. I too understand that it has gone too far for comments. But just to make it clear i did not ask about making the html code for making a table. I have not found a way to permute the values in `serialize`  in my answer. But Iwill figure it out. Thanks a lot fro all your comments.. :) :)

Comment: The question is: what is the point of " found a way to permute the values in serialize in my answer."? You have the values in the right positions. You want to store this information in a properly-structured way to access it at a later point for whatever reason? OK, do it (although I recommend to replace the 3D tuples with a better approach). But you don't need to spend even 1 sec. to print out a table. You have everything already! Why wasting memory resources, effort and over-complicating things so much? Anyway... I hope that my position is clear and that you found helpful something I said.

Comment: in my tuple i have the result this way : `serailize["colour","blue","yellow","black","red"}]` (one sample in serailize but with my real data). I shoudl make combinations with the inner list when i do not know how many forloops would do the job. But really thanks. i can probably do it. Sorry I wasted your time. :(

Comment: If you understand the idea, you wouldn't have wasted my time: what is the point of serialising?! You have already a loop. You can use the loop to output anything you want; for example: ready to use HTML code. You want to store variables and then convert the stored variables in the format which you might have had in a first moment! The code which you (or others) created is meant to ease the new code you will be creating, not to complicate it unnecessarily. If you don't need to serialise now why forcing your code to use it?...

Comment: There are only two options: either wanting to create a set of variables following certain structure to meet whatever goal (e.g., accessing such an information at a later point by following exactly this structure); or wanting to output the given results (HTML code in this case). If you are interested in the second option, you wouldn't need the first one. You can output the results right away. Is the HTML being generated in a different part of the code and you want to keep a consistent structure? Then move the loops to this part, because they belong there. Why complicating what is so simple?

Comment: I am not talking about the sample loop I have created with constant number of inputs. But my second code where serialise is used just as a variable name and doesnt exactly mean it. I have done the same thing similar to `colorval`, `fruitval` and `vegval` in serialize. i do not want to get into a state of argument/hatred so that you dont feel like helping me ever. But I understand that my explanations about my answer that I have posted isnt clear enough. I have a view where this needs to displayed. But passing that isnt my trouble. But to get the list of values that could make a row.

Comment: Ah! Sorry; I misunderstood this point. As said the complexity increase from constant number to variable number is certainly relevant (and too problematic as far it is too prone to errors). I am afraid that this is a battle you have to fight by your own :) bye.

Comment: I think i should think of other method making this work. My current approach is not gonna help. I should give it a fresh start. byee :)

Comment: @varocarbas : Sorry to bother you again. I just wanted to let you know that I could find a solution to the problem. Though not good as Enigmativity 's answer. Its just something that I could think of.

Comment: Please, don't get offended and try to understand the following ideas: I tried to help you the first time, because I saw you completely lost (you were asking in the wrong way and your algorithm was crazily wrong); but my intention was just helping to understand your mistakes (at least, regarding this site) and move on. The conversation got too long in a way which is off-topic hereand which I didn't like at all. But I am a person who always answers anyway (ignoring someone's question is, IMHO, a lack of respect)...

Comment: ... The only reason why I might want to help you or any other asker is because their problems are generic enough and, eventually, helpful to others. People coming here with their problems, only concerned about the problems and wanting to solve their problems; are completely off-topic and, as such, not worthy-of-help for me. Thus, this thing of I "finally solve my problem" (a problem you provoked yourself) is honestly completely and absolutely irrelevant for me and/or SO...

Comment: I really do not get the point of your message though. I just wanted to let you know i found an answer because you guided me in the right direction. So i was showing gratitude to my `teacher` for helping me. And i am not offended in any way. And I told `the problem`  and never `my problem`. And posted the answer so that someone else can look into it in case they encounter the same problem. :). I really do not understand how i was being dishonest?

Comment: ... what is not so irrelevant is the behaviour you are showing that is not too honest (again try to get offended, but this is what I see): you were completely lost; I said you what to do step by step; while implementing the suggestion (= an answer to your question = a solution to your problem in that moment), you realised that you were asking the wrong question and re-format it, what is also off-topic here...

Comment: (Thanks for interrupting my message, with a "not get the point"... wait until I finish and read it properly and perhaps you would get it)... regarding to your interruption: this whole post is not helpful to anyone; you have learned from your errors (+ counting with step-by-step help), but perhaps your conclusions are still wrong, I will not waste my time analysing it. This is not helpful to anyone else, just to you. Anyway... PD: if you think that Enigmativity's answer is so good (not sure in its current version, but originally I did prefer the loops), you should upvote it.

Comment: so all i wanted was to thank you again for the help. Now a thanks on a higher level because i was able to find a solution. And I haven't tried his solution yet coz he gave a complete description some time before. But i have upvoted it for his effort on this complicated task. Will accept his soln once i get the output with his approach. :).. And no offence.

Comment: I see how you upvoted his answer right after I suggested it in my comment above (by the way, the +1 you got is mine; but wasn't meant for its current version, but for the original 3 loops actually addressing your original question). Seriously, try to use SO as intended (this is not like SE Programmers) and try to avoid long discussions which are not helpful to anyone; that is: try to avoid saying me anything because a long discussion will certainly happen :) I hope that my contribution to this post can end here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
Func<string[][], string[][]> build = null;
build = s =>
    s.Length == 1
        ? s[0].Select(x => new [] { x }).ToArray()
        : build(s.Skip(1).ToArray())
            .SelectMany(xs => s[0].Select(x => new [] { x }.Concat(xs).ToArray()))
            .ToArray();
```

This base case in this query, when `s.Length == 1` basically turns `new [] { new [] { "onion", "potato", "tomato", "beans" } }` into `new [] { new [] { "onion", }, new [] { "potato", }, new [] { "tomato", }, new [] { "beans", }, }`. The non-base case recursively calls `build` and then appends to the beginning of each recursed array the first array's values. Glad you asked?

Alternatively I could have written this query like this:

```
Func<string[][], string[][]> build = null;
build = s =>
(
    s.Length == 1
        ? from x in s[0] select new [] { x }
        : from xs in build(s.Skip(1).ToArray())
          from x in s[0] select new [] { x }.Concat(xs).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

That may help you to break it down easier.

If I start with this data:

```
var source = new []
{
    new { Key = "colour", Value = "red", },
    new { Key = "colour", Value = "blue", },
    new { Key = "colour", Value = "violet", },
    new { Key = "colour", Value = "black", },
    new { Key = "colour", Value = "yellow", },
    new { Key = "fruit", Value = "apple", },
    new { Key = "fruit", Value = "mango", },
    new { Key = "fruit", Value = "banana", },
    new { Key = "vegetable", Value = "onion", },
    new { Key = "vegetable", Value = "potato", },
    new { Key = "vegetable", Value = "tomato", },
    new { Key = "vegetable", Value = "beans", },
};

string[][] data =
    source
        .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
        .Select(x => x.ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

I get this result:

```
new []
{
   new [] { "red", "apple", "onion" } 
   new [] { "blue", "apple", "onion" } 
   new [] { "violet", "apple", "onion" } 
   new [] { "black", "apple", "onion" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "apple", "onion" } 
   new [] { "red", "mango", "onion" } 
   new [] { "blue", "mango", "onion" } 
   new [] { "violet", "mango", "onion" } 
   new [] { "black", "mango", "onion" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "mango", "onion" } 
   new [] { "red", "banana", "onion" } 
   new [] { "blue", "banana", "onion" } 
   new [] { "violet", "banana", "onion" } 
   new [] { "black", "banana", "onion" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "banana", "onion" } 
   new [] { "red", "apple", "potato" } 
   new [] { "blue", "apple", "potato" } 
   new [] { "violet", "apple", "potato" } 
   new [] { "black", "apple", "potato" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "apple", "potato" } 
   new [] { "red", "mango", "potato" } 
   new [] { "blue", "mango", "potato" } 
   new [] { "violet", "mango", "potato" } 
   new [] { "black", "mango", "potato" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "mango", "potato" } 
   new [] { "red", "banana", "potato" } 
   new [] { "blue", "banana", "potato" } 
   new [] { "violet", "banana", "potato" } 
   new [] { "black", "banana", "potato" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "banana", "potato" } 
   new [] { "red", "apple", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "blue", "apple", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "violet", "apple", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "black", "apple", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "apple", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "red", "mango", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "blue", "mango", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "violet", "mango", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "black", "mango", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "mango", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "red", "banana", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "blue", "banana", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "violet", "banana", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "black", "banana", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "banana", "tomato" } 
   new [] { "red", "apple", "beans" } 
   new [] { "blue", "apple", "beans" } 
   new [] { "violet", "apple", "beans" } 
   new [] { "black", "apple", "beans" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "apple", "beans" } 
   new [] { "red", "mango", "beans" } 
   new [] { "blue", "mango", "beans" } 
   new [] { "violet", "mango", "beans" } 
   new [] { "black", "mango", "beans" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "mango", "beans" } 
   new [] { "red", "banana", "beans" } 
   new [] { "blue", "banana", "beans" } 
   new [] { "violet", "banana", "beans" } 
   new [] { "black", "banana", "beans" } 
   new [] { "yellow", "banana", "beans" } 
}
```

This works with any number of keys.

Try this data:

```
var source = new []
{
    new { Key = "colour", Value = "red", },
    new { Key = "fruit", Value = "apple", },
    new { Key = "vegetable", Value = "onion", },
    new { Key = "nation", Value = "france", },
    new { Key = "nation", Value = "australia", },
};
```

I get this result:

```
new []
{
   new [] { "red", "apple", "onion", "france" } 
   new [] { "red", "apple", "onion", "australia" } 
}
```

---

If your key is an `int` then the code works just the same:

```
var source = new[]
{
    new { Key = 1, Value = "red", },
    new { Key = 1, Value = "apple", },
    new { Key = 2, Value = "onion", },
    new { Key = 3, Value = "france", },
    new { Key = 3, Value = "australia", },
};

string[][] data =
    source
        .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
        .Select(x => x.ToArray())
        .ToArray();

Func<string[][], string[][]> build = null;
build = s =>
(
    s.Length == 1
        ? from x in s[0] select new[] { x }
        : from xs in build(s.Skip(1).ToArray())
          from x in s[0]
          select new[] { x }.Concat(xs).ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

---

Here's non-anonymous version of `build`:

```
public string[][] Build(string[][] source)
{
    return
    (
        source.Length == 1
            ? from x in source[0] select new[] { x }
            : from xs in Build(source.Skip(1).ToArray())
              from x in source[0]
              select new[] { x }.Concat(xs).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - Done, but it's probably not overly helpful.

Comment: Really I need some time to understand that query it seems. I have never come across something like that before. And as mentioned in my question the number of key or the values are now known until execution. But thanks for your answer. I will surely try it once i really get your point.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - My solution works with any number of keys. I've tried to show that with the second example where I added the `"nation"` key.

Comment: I understand that. But how do i write the query if the number of sets are unknown.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - I added a refactored solution which may be easier to work through.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - This already works with an unknown number of sets. That's the beauty of recursion.

Comment: Let me ask you the most stupid question. Why do you have 2 2D arrays passed to the function build? Let me assume the first one to be the input source. What is the second one? And I do not understand what parameters could be passed to the function build. My 2D list is of the format `<int,string>`. Can't I apply this type in function build even if I change the function declaration to `function<int[],string[][]>`

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - It doesn't matter if your key is an integer, the code is still the exactly the same. `Func<string[][], string[][]>` means that it is a function that takes a single jagged array of strings and returns a jagged array of strings.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - I've added the code for when the key is an `int`. It doesn't change.

Comment: I am going to try your approach now. I have found another way of doing it as well and added in my answer; though not good (should sound really stupid for you :) ). Again how does build know data and source should be used as parameters for the function build? I never used anonymous functions in my code. Isn't this function called anonymous function?

Comment: @ViniVasundharan - Yes, it is an anonymous function. I'll add a normal definition too for you.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a real answer for the question. But an approach that could be followed when the number of variables are fixed. This approach could be extended  for variable inputs

```
   public ActionResult tablecreate()
    {
        string[] key = { "colour", "fruit", "vegetable" };
        var kvpair = new List<Tuple<String,String>>();
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String,String>("colour","red"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("colour", "blue"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("colour", "yellow"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("colour", "black"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("fruit", "mango"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("fruit", "apple"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("vegetable", "potato"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("vegetable", "tomato"));
        kvpair.Add(new Tuple<String, String>("vegetable", "beans"));
        var combi = new List<Tuple<String,String,String>>();
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        var colorval = new List<String>();
        var fruitval = new List<String>();
        var vegval =new List<String>();
        foreach (var item in kvpair)
        {
            if (item.Item1 == "colour")
                colorval.Add(item.Item2);
            else if (item.Item1 == "fruit")
                fruitval.Add(item.Item2);
            else if (item.Item1 == "vegetable")
                vegval.Add(item.Item2);
        }
        foreach(var col in colorval)
        {
            foreach(var fru in fruitval)
            {
                foreach(var veg in vegval)
                {
                    combi.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(col, fru, veg));
                }
            }
        }
```

The output would generate the table mentioned in the question

i could get the values that belong to each key with the following code, still making the combinations are missing

```
  var serialize = new List<Tuple<int, List<string>>>();

 for(int i=0;i<tcid.Count();i++)
 {
       var val = new List<string>();
       foreach(var item in model)
       {
           if(tcid[i]==item.TcSetID)
                val.Add(item.Value);        
       }
       serialize.Add(new Tuple<int,List<string>>(tcid[i],val));
  }
```

Now in `serailize` we have all possible values for each key.

To make it more clear `serailize` is used only as a variable name. the serailise list is similar to the `colorval`, `fruitval` and `vegval`  in the above code with constant number of variables.

So serailize will hold values as below :

```
serialize [item1 :colour, item2 : {blue,red,black,yellow}]
serialize [item1 :fruit, item2 : {apple,mango}]
serialize [item1 :vegetable, item2 : {tomato,potato,beans}]
```

I have a function that will find the cartesian product of two items in `serialize.item2`

```
public List<String> Cartesian (List<String> A, List<String> B)
{
    int Alenght = A.Count();
    int Blength = B.Count();
    var S = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Alenght;i++ )
    {
       for(int j=0;j<Blength;j++)
       {
           S.Add(A[i] + "delim" + B[j]);
       }
    }
    return S;
}
```

And the function is called as follows

```
 var A = new List<String>();
 foreach(var item in serialize)
 {
     if(j==0)
     {
         A = item.Item2;
         j = 1;    
     }
     else
         A =  Cartesian(A, item.Item2);
  }
```

Then to to make the string in the list `A` as string Array

```
 //distinctlist contains all the distinct strings in A
 foreach(var item in distinctlist)
 {
     var row = new ViewsVM();
     row.row = item.Split(new string[] { "delim"},StringSplitOptions.None);
     ViewsVM.Add(row);
 }
```

**ViewsVM**

```
public class ViewsVM
{ 
    public string[] row  { get; set; }
}
```

Hope it helps someone. But I should warn this isnt the best approach.

**Enigmativity** has a better approach for the problem. I posted this answer just because I also found an alternative to do this.